# How to create Triggers on oracle indexes

Tags: oracle, indexing, triggers

to be more clear
I want to create a trigger that fires each time a new index is created in my schema
and then save that index name in a separate table let's call it index_log.

in index_log table, there is a *creation_time* column that tells the creation time of said index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get only the index name and creation time, then you don't need any trigger as demonstrated by @Littlefoot.

Otherwise you can create a [DDL-Trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm#i6061):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit_index 
   AFTER CREATE ON hr.SCHEMA 
   WHEN (ora_dict_obj_type = 'INDEX')
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Index Name: ' || ora_dict_obj_name);
END;
/
```

You should have a look at [Triggers for Publishing Events](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-2951D8A6-6C80-428F-840D-13A76A97E365) to get desired information from trigger event.

Answer (score 3):

Reinventing the wheel, are we? That information is stored in `USER_OBJECTS`, I suggest you use it.

Info:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
28.12.2020 16:20:11
```

Table:

```
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.
```

Index:

```
SQL> create index i1t on test (id);

Index created.
```

When was it created?

```
SQL> select created from user_objects where object_name = 'I1T';

CREATED
-------------------
28.12.2020 16:20:20

SQL>
```

Comment: I'm doing this for a school assignment, my teacher wants me to reinvent the wheel for him.
that's why I was having trouble in the first place, Like why should I create a separate log tables for indexes when I can just get that info using the way you mentioned.
but I have to do it using triggers, i hope you can help me with that.

Comment: You should have said so. Anyway, Wernfried already answered your question so - I hope it is done now.